# Calculate $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3})/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm attempting some of my first problems in solving for Galois Groups, and this one has stumped me.

What I've done so far is found that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3})$ is not a normal extension, because the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[5]{3}$ is $x^5-3$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3})$ is not the splitting field of this polynomial.

So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3})$ is not normal, thus not a Galois Extension. I know if it was a Galois extension you can determine the order of the Galois Group since it equals the degree of the extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. But for an extension that is not Galois I can only get that the degree of the extension is an upper bound on the order of the Galois group. And from here I don't know where to go...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your definition of the Galois group the group of automorphisms of the extension?

Comment: Yes that's the definition I am using!

Comment: Consider writing $\text{Aut}(E/F)$ rather than $\text{Gal}(E/F)$ when it's not a Galois extension, so that it's obvious what you mean.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I agree that making a notational distinction is better (I am a late convert, I persisted in always writing $\mathrm{Gal}$ until much later than my first exposure to Galois theory).

Comment: Noted, thanks for the pointer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Step 1: Show that any automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[5]{3})$ is determined by its action on $\sqrt[5]{3}$.

Step 2: If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[5]{3})$ show that $\sigma(\sqrt[5]{3})=\sqrt[5]{3}$.